# How do I get jQuery Sortable to work with Table cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I know how to get sortable to work when each row is a specific item. But I'm curious how I would do it with a table where each row contains cells that have the specific items. I can't seem to get the items to switch properly. Within a certain row the items switch fine. But if I move an item between rows the row just grows horizontally. Any ideas?

I'm currently calling sortable on table with item being td. But like I said, when I move an item between rows the row just grows horizontally and the item doesn't switch to the other tr properly.

Current Code (coffeescript):

```
$( "tbody" ).sortable
    items: 'td'
```

Comment: Please share the code you've so far, or better a code snippet demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @TJ Added. And the table is just a simple HTML table with a 3xn structure.

Comment: The shared code makes tables rows sortable. I don't think that is when you're having an issue. Please share the whole code - HTML/CSS/JS that is required o reproduce whatever is the issue you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
<table>
  <tr class="sortable">
    <th>Title</th>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
     ...

​$( '​​​​.sortable' ).sortable({
    items: 'td'
});​​​​​
```

Comment: The problem with that is that the cells would only be sortable within their respective row, and I need the cells to be able to freely move throughout the table. But if I instead put the class on the table or the tbody, the cells can freely move but the table does not sort properly. So if the table is 3x3 and I move a cell from the second row to the first row, the cell will add to the first row correctly but the first row will then have 4 cells.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the result I wanted by changing the display of the `tr` to `display: inline` and changing `td` to `display: inline-block`. That allowed me to get the correct functionality.